# How to generate a string with a list of skipped record ids

Tags: apex

Here I am skipping the records for which there is no matching count__c.
I need to concatinate a string (skippedRecords) with ids of those skipped records. How would I achive this?

```
List<Data__c > datatoupdate = new List<Data__c >();

String skippedRecords = '';
    for(Data__c dRecords : dList) { 
        for(Parent__c parentRecords : parentList) {
            if(dRecords.count__c  == parentRecords.count__c) {
                dRecords.downloads__c  = parentRecords.downloads__c ;
                datatoupdate.add(dRecords );
            }
    } 
} 
update  datatoupdate;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can collect the Id in a `List` and use the built-in `String.join()`.
For example:

```java
List<Id> skippedRecords = new List<Id>();
skippedRecords.add(id1); //just an example, id1 should be the record Id
skippedRecords.add(id2);
...

String.join(skippedRecords, ','); // id1,id2
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up creating this. Not sure if this is the ideal solution, but it worked:

```
String skippedRecords = '';
Integer checkedParentIds = 0;
Boolean idMatch = false;
Integer totalParentIds = parentList.size();

for(Data__c dRecords : dList) {
    idMatch = false;
    totalParentIds = parentList.size();
    checkedParentIds = 0;
    for(Parent__c parentRecs : parentList) {
        checkedParentIds++;
        if(dRecords.count__c  == parentRecs.count__c) {
            dRecords.downloads__c  = parentRecords.downloads__c;
            ddRecsToInsert.add(dRecords);
            idMatch = true;
            break;
        } else if ((checkedParentIds == totalParentIds) && (idMatch == false)) {
            skippedRecords += dRecords.count__c + '\n';
        }
    } 
}
```